# navigationController!.pushViewController vs. presentViewController in iOS Swift

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

What are the implications of pushing a ViewController in UINavigation vs. presenting a ViewController modally in terms of changing values in the next view?

For example, why does the first work but not the second?

First:

```
var textController: TextViewController
textController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TextViewController") as! TextViewController
presentViewController(textController, animated: false, completion: nil)
textController.textDetail.text = Categories[indexPath.row]
```

Second:

```
var textController: TextViewController
textController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TextViewController") as! TextViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(textController,animated:true)
textController.textDetail.text = Categories[indexPath.row]
```

I can't get the label's value to change when pushing in a navigation stack.

Comment: 1. How are you instantiating `textController`? 2. How are you instantiating `textDetail`? Assuming 1. textController is a UIViewController, and 2. you have just instantiated `textController` prior to this code in both cases, and 3. `textDetail` is an IBOutlet, it will not be instantiated during the initialization process of `textController`, and it won't be available to set its text value in either case, you need to wait for later in the View Controller lifecycle.

Comment: I added the code that instantiates it. The first one does change the label's value but the second gives me an unwrapping error

Comment: Where's the unwrapping error occurring? Is it occurring on the line: `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(textController,animated:true)` ? If not: Are these two blocks of code happening in the same place in your viewController code? How are you instantiating `textDetail`?

Comment: It happens on the textDetail.text assignment. I'm not instantiating textDetail anywhere. I'm only using one block at a time. The first one works but when I change the code to the second, I get the unwrapping error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though when calling the `presentViewController` method, the view of the view controller is actually loaded during the call, whereas when calling the `pushViewController` on the navigation controller, the view itself is loaded after the call.

You can test this yourself by printing to the console before and after presenting/pushing the view controller, and printing to the console in the TextViewController's `viewDidLoad` method.

The view needs to be loaded for the `textDetail` variable to load (you haven't said so, but I'm assuming this is an IBOutlet) and the `textDetail` variable needs to load for you to be able to modify its `text` property.

To use `pushViewController` you could for example set a variable on your `TextViewController` class, and override its `viewDidLoad` method, where you could then set the text property on the `textDetail` variable.